# How to shorten a repetitive recursive block of CSS

Tags: css

Because of the repetitive nature of the CSS block below, I'm wondering if it can be shortened.

`.effort` is a `<div>`, containing:

- a child `<span>` element `.effortTitle`
- a child `<div>` element `.effort` containing
- etc

```
    .effortNode .effortTitle{
        padding-left:20px;
    }
    .effortNode .effortNode .effortTitle{
        padding-left:40px;
    }
    .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortTitle{
        padding-left:60px;
    }
    .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortTitle{
        padding-left:80px;
    }
    .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortTitle{
        padding-left:100px;
    }
    .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortNode .effortTitle{
        padding-left:120px;
    }
    etc...
```

Comment: it's good to know the use case of such thing. Probably *thinking differently* is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write this more efficently in SCSS / SASS.

https://sass-lang.com/

Read up on the syntax, its super easy to use.

Answer (score -2):

**Update**

Instead of using SCSS, it can be done much easier with just CSS:

```
.effortNode * {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

It adds `20px` padding for each child element in `.effortNode`.

---

[Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aaVOQN).

*Note: I've used `margin-left` instead of `padding`, so you can see how it works.*

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to calculate the ...px value?
Something like parent + 20?

Comment: Absolutely. You can write functions (called [mixins](https://sass-lang.com/guide)) that can dynamically write complete blocks of CSS. I'm not sure how to write your example in a much shorter way, but you should take a look / use the playground!

Comment: Why the downvotes on this? Seems to answer the question nicely with plain CSS.

Comment: @JedRichards My previous answer recommended SCSS. Still don't understand the downvotes though, because OP asked for *any* solution.